# How to install an R package to R-3.3.0 from GitHub, which is built on R-3.4.0?

Tags: r

We have R-3.3.0 in our university's computing system. For some reason, the IT staffs do not want to update R version to R-3.4.0 soon. However, I need to install an R package from the GitHub, which is built on R-3.4.0. Is there any way to install that R package from the GitHub's to R-3.3.0?

Comment: Which package? Many will still install just fine in R-3.3 without modification. You might need to go back through the repo's history to find a specific commit point that changed the requirement from 3.3 to 3.4, and then use the previous commit, such as `devtools::install_github("dir/repo", ref="b72a228")`.

Comment: @r2evans The package name is OPWeight, which is recently updated after major modification on R-3.4.

Comment: You can also download it and mess with the _Description_ file [(link)](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/description.html) by changing the `Depends` value. Obviously a last resort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the description file for OPWeight [here](https://github.com/mshasan/OPWeight/blob/master/DESCRIPTION).

Change this part

> Depends: 
>       R (>= 3.4.0),

to whatever R you are using and see if things break. The logic of the description file is explained [here](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/description.html). Obviously a last resort.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: If you're accepting this answer, then the least you can do is [submit an issue](https://github.com/mshasan/OPWeight/issues) to the repo maintainer asking them to reset the dependency back to 3.3, since it apparently works just fine. Assuming they respond (they have 0 issues so far), they'll either say "Sure!" in which case you're good, or they'll give you the reason they believe 3.4 is required.

Answer (score 2):

@patrick's answer may work just fine. The benefit (if it works) is that you have all recent changes and functionality of the package. However, you may never know if one of the changes requiring 3.4 is about accuracy or correctness, meaning you may still get a return value but you don't necessarily know that it is correct.

For this answer, I'm going to assume that there is a valid reason to not use the current version and trick R into installing it anyway.

### Grab from a specific commit

1. Go to the repo, https://github.com/mshasan/OPWeight in this case.
2. Open the `DESCRIPTION` file and click on the "Blame" button on the right. This brings up the commit message-header and timeframe for each group of lines with their most recent commit. In this case, it shows "Update DESCRIPTION":

   [image]
3. Click on the description, and you're taken to the specific commit. Seeing that this is a single-line change, it is likely that an earlier commit may have been what actually changed code to use `R (>= 3.4.0)` a hard requirement. Take note of the commit hash (`5c0a43c` in this case).
4. Go back to the repo main page and click on "Commits". If you now search for that 7-char hash-substring, you'll see it happened on June 20, 2017. Unfortunately, the commit descriptions and timeline do not give a great expectation of where the version-depending change happened.
5. If you can find "the commit" that did it, then take that hash-substring and use that as your `ref="..."` argument to `install_github`. If not, however, you are either stuck (1) trying them iteratively or randomly, or (2) asking the author at which commit they started using 3.4-specific code.

Once you know a ref to use (or want to try), then run

```
devtools::install_github("mshasen/OPWeight", ref="5c0a43c")
```

(This is obviously the wrong ref to use, since that's the first commit at which we are *certain* the dependency exists.)

### Using tests to know which to use

Since the repo contains a `tests/` subdir, one can hope/assume that the tests will accurately catch if things are not working correctly in your R-3.3. This alternative method involves you testing each commit on your specific version of R (before the `DESCRIPTION` file was changed) until the tests no longer fail.

Using `git` (command-line or GUI), clone the repo to your local computer.

```
$ git glone https://github.com/mshasan/OPWeight
```

Now, iterate through the references (found using the above method or perhaps with `git log`) with something like:

```
$ git checkout --detach <hash_substring>
```

... and in R, run

```
devtools::test("path/to/your/copy/of/OPWeight")
```

If the tests have been set up correctly and you chose a worthy version, then stick with it.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanations. I follow that.